# Javascript Prototypal Inheritance & object properties shadowing

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

```
var person = { name :"dummy", personal_details: { age : 22, country : "USA" } };

var bob = Object.create(person);

bob.name = "bob";
bob.personal_details.age = 23;


console.log(bob.personal_details === person.personal_details);
// true : since it does not shadow object of prototype object

console.log(bob.name  === person.name);
// false : since it shadows name

////now
bob.personal_details  = {a:1};
console.log(bob.personal_details === person.personal_details);
```

//false

When object ***bob*** tries to override "***name***" property of ***person*** then, it gets shadowed in bob itself.

But in case of **personal_details** the same rule is violated.

I am quite curious to know why is it like so ??

**Here is the link to jsbin : http://jsbin.com/asuzev/1/edit**

Comment: @Marcell, There is nothing like copying over here...bob's __proto__ will point to person .(bob.__proto__ === person will be true..)

Comment: Yes there is. the reference to the only instance of `.personal_details` is copied.

Comment: To be more exact, the only instance of `personal_details` is created from the object literal only ONCE and (its reference is) assigned the `person` object. Then that reference is coped to `bob` but there's still only one `personal_details`. Therefore changing a member of `personal_details` in either `bob` or `person` will change it in both.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What is going on can be illustrated quite easily with a few examples:

#### Accessing personal_details via the prototype chain

```
var person = { name :"dummy", personal_details: { age : 22, country : "USA" } }
var bob = Object.create(person)

bob.name = "bob"
bob.personal_details.age = 23
```

Which outputs like:

```
console.log( bob );
/// { name :"bob", personal_details: { age : 23, country : "USA" } }

console.log( person )
/// { name :"dummy", personal_details: { age : 23, country : "USA" } }
```

Age 23 is now set on the person object `because bob.personal_details` is a direct reference to `person.personal_details` via bob's prototype chain. Once you navigate down the object structure you are working directly with the `person.personal_details` object.

#### Overriding a prototyped property with a local property

However if you override bob's `personal_details` property with another object, that prototype link will be overridden by a more local property.

```
bob.personal_details = { a: 123 }
```

Now the output is:

```
console.log( bob );
/// { name :"bob", personal_details: { a : 123 } }

console.log( person )
/// { name :"dummy", personal_details: { age : 23, country : "USA" } }
```

So by accessing `bob.personal_details`—from now on—you are referencing the `{ a: 123 }` object not the original `{ age : 23, country : "USA" }` object of person. All changes made will occur on that object and basically have nothing to do with `bob` or the `person` object.

#### The Prototype chain

To make things interesting, what do you think happens when you do this, after all the above:

```
delete bob.personal_details
```

You end up reviving the original prototype link to `person.personal_details` (because you've removed the local property you added), so a console log would reveal:

```
console.log( bob );
/// { name :"bob", personal_details: { age : 23, country : "USA" } }
```

Basically the JavaScript engine will work its way back along the prototype chain, until it finds the property or method you are requesting on each prototype object. The further up the chain an item is set, will mean it will override the others later on down.

Now another question, what happens if you fire off the following again?

```
delete bob.personal_details
```

Nothing, there is no longer an actual property assigned to bob called `personal_details`, `delete` will only work on the current object and not follow down the prototype chain.

#### A different way of looking at it

Another way of looking at how the prototype chain works is basically imagining a stack of objects. When JavaScript scans for a particular property or method it would read downwards through the following structure:

```
bob :          {  }
  person :     { name: 'dummy', personal_details: { age: 22 } }
    Object :   { toString: function(){ return '[Object object]'; } }
```

So as an example, say I wanted to access `bob.toString`. `toString` is a method that exists on JavaScript's base object `Object` which is the base prototype for nearly everything. When the interpreter gets a read-request for a particular method or property on an object it will follow this chain of events:

1. Does `bob` have a property called `toString`? **No.**
2. Does `bob.__proto__` i.e. `person` have a property called `toString`? **No.**
3. Does `bob.__proto__.__proto__` i.e. `Object` have a property called `toString`? **Yes**
4. Return the reference to `function(){ return '[Object object]'; }`

Once it reaches point 4 the interpreter will have returned the reference to the `toString` method found on Object. If the property hadn't been found on `Object` an error of *undefined property* would most likely have been fired (because it is the last in the chain).

Now if we take the example before, and this time define a `toString` method on `bob` - so:

```
bob :          { toString: function(){ return '[Bob]'; } }
  person :     { name: 'dummy', personal_details: { age: 22 } }
    Object :   { toString: function(){ return '[Object object]'; } }
```

If we try and read-access the `toString` method on bob again, this time we get:

1. Does `bob` have a property called `toString`? **Yes.**

The process stops at the first hurdle and returns the `toString` method from bob. This means that `bob.toString()` will return `[Bob]` rather than `[Object object]`.

As has been succinctly stated by Phant0m write requests on an object follow a different path and will never travel down the prototype chain. Understanding this is to work out the difference between what is a read, and what is a write request.

```
bob.toString                   --- is a read request
bob.toString = function(){}    --- is a write request
bob.personal_details           --- is a read request
bob.personal_details = {}      --- is a write request
bob.personal_details.age = 123 --- is a read request, then a write request.
```

The last item is the one that is causing confusion. And the process would follow this route:

1. Does `bob` have a property called `personal_details`? **No.**
2. Does `person` have a property called `personal_details`? **Yes.**
3. Return the reference to `{ age: 22 }` which is stored floating somewhere in memory.

Now a new process is started because each part of an object navigation or assignment is a new request for a property or method. So, now we have our `personal_details` object we switch to a write request, because a property or variable on the left had side of an `=` equals is always an assignment.

1. Write the value `123` to the property `age` on the object `{ age: 22 }`

So the original request could be seen as something like this:

```
(bob.personal_details)            --- read
    (personal_details.age = 123)  --- write
```

If `bob` had owned its own property of `personal_details` the process would have been the same but the target object being written to would have been different.

#### And finally...

Put along the lines of your question:

> Its difficult to digest that properties on prototype objects are treated as READ_ONLY, but if property is an object then one can get hold of it and can freely modify its properties !! Is my understanding right ?

Prototyped properties are seemingly read-only, but only when accessed directly as a property of the object that is inheriting them -- because those properties don't actually exist on the inheriting object at all. If you navigate down to the prototype object itself it can then be treated just as any normal object *(with read and write)* because that is exactly what it is — a normal object. It might be confusing initially, but this is the nature or prototype inheritance, it's all about how you access the properties you're working with.

Comment: Its difficult to digest that properties on prototype objects are treated as READ_ONLY, but if property is an object then one can get hold of it and can freely modify its properties !! Is my understanding right ?

Comment: The rules are simple: Assigning to an object's property only affects that very object, nothing else.

Comment: @Ashish I've updated my answer with a slightly different way of looking at it. Your statement is roughly correct, but as Phant0m has pointed out you are complicating the issue by being human, and keeping the relationship between an object--with an property that is also an object--in your mind when applying thinking about these read and write operations. A JavaScript interpreter breaks everything down to singular objects and singular properties when performing read or write tasks (with no relationship to "parent" objects). Parents are an illusion -- at least for JavaScript Objects.

Comment: I have finished studying prototype recently, and I have to say, this is the best explanation I'v came across so far. This should really get more up-votes. +1 from me

Answer (score 3):

You don't assign to a property of `bob` in the second case, so how could you override it?

In the case of `bob.name = "bob"`, you bind bob's *own* name property.

In the second case, you *don't*. You access bob's `personal_details` property–via the prototype. You then assign to a property of that object, all connection to `bob` is lost by that time.

Think of it like this:

```
bob.personal_details.age = 23;
// equivalent
expr = bob.personal_details;
expr.age = 23; // As you can see, there's no assignment to bob
```

It doesn't violate any rules, because the case is completely different.

Comment: bob.personal_details  = {a:1}; // now personal_details is not located  using prototype inheritance ? why its being shadowed into bob itself ?

Comment: You assign to bob's property, which is why it shadows person's personal_details attribute. It's the same situation as `bob.name = "bob"`.

Comment: so u mean until I access bob.personal_details.<property> , bob is not going to reference prototype object's  personal_details object ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you arrive at that conclusion, but no, that is not at all what I wanted to say. `bob` does *not* have a property called `personal_details` until you assign `{a:1}}`. Before that, the lookup always goes through the prototype chain.

Answer (score 3):

I hope that the diagram bellow is clear enough, but I'll try to explain in short what's happening.

When you create new object with `Object.create` you create an object with prototype the first argument of the method `create`. So you create `bob` with prototype which points to the `person` object. All properties of `person` are accessible by `bob` through the reference to it's prototype.

In the next picture you change `bob`'s name. It's now `bob` so simply you create new `slot` or `property` of `bob` which name is `name` (now the interpreter won't check the prototype chain when looking for property `name` it'll directly find that bob has such property).

In the third one you change `bob.personal_details.age` which affects to `person.personal_details.age` because simply that's the same object.

At last you set the property `personal_details`, now `bob` has slot `personal_details`, it's not a prototype property it's a reference to another object - the anonymous one.

[image]