# changing value in prototype does not work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype, javascript-scope

I am new in JS, lets have a look on my code bellow.

I want to change value of legs property of mouse to 2 while using **proto** but I am unable to change it. All I am getting in output is 4. Please help why is this ?

```js
function Animal() {
  this.legs = 4;
}

var mouse = new Animal();

mouse.__proto__.legs = 2;
console.log(mouse.legs);
```

Comment: That's not the right dupe, I think this one would work though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379208/javascript-prototypal-inheritance-object-properties-shadowing . The `legs` property on the instance object itself overrides the `legs` property on the prototype

Comment: That is because the leg you are referring is a self property and not on prototype.

Comment: `while using proto` - why?

Comment: @Rajesh so even if adding mouse.__proto__.legs = 2; doesn't makes any legs property on prototype? 
or it adds? but is not accessible from prototype because browser has found legs property of mouse on its self and that's why not going into prototype chain to lookup legs propert, am I right?

Comment: @Archer just because I am heading around prototypes in JS.

Comment: `__proto__` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), use `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. Rajesh has your answer: `mouse.legs` accesses the *legs* property of *mouse*, not its `[[Prototype]]`. Property resolution starts at the object and only goes up the prototype chain if no own property is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, the leg you are trying to access is a self owned property and not on prototype.

Following is a sample:

```js
function Animal() {
  this.legs = 4;
}
Animal.prototype.legs = 8;
var mouse = new Animal();

mouse.legs = 2;
console.log(mouse.legs, mouse.__proto__.legs);
```

---

That said, if you wish to have a override concept implementation, always remember, never mutate/change property on prototype.

Idea is to have common property on prototype and have custom property on self.

Following is a sample depicting the same:

```js
function Animal() { this.legs = 4; }
function Reptile() { this.legs = 4; }

Reptile.prototype = new Animal();
var mouse = new Reptile();
console.log('Mouse details : ', mouse.legs, mouse.__proto__.legs);

var snake = new Reptile();
snake.leg = 0;
console.log('Snake details : ', snake.legs, snake.__proto__.legs);

snake.__proto__.legs = 0;

console.log('After mutation')

console.log('Mouse details : ', mouse.legs, mouse.__proto__.legs);
console.log('Snake details : ', snake.legs, snake.__proto__.legs);
```

---

To simply put, everything in JS is an object. When you create an object, it has 2 nested levels by default:

-> this
 -> __proto__

Any property of your constructor goes to `this`. Any property on its prototype goes to `__proto__`. Since all objects are inherited from `Object`, there is a chain till global object.

Comment: In other words its about scope chain

Comment: Exactly! It is about that only

Answer (score 1):

You can't change instance property this way.

`mouse.__proto__` contains constructor function `Animal`.

If you want to change only mouse's legs you have to do it this way:
`mouse.legs = 2`

If you want to change every future animals - you unfortunately can't. `new Animal()` will always reference to original constructor function.

When you call `new Animal`, the JS engine doesn't reference `Animal.prototype.constructor`, it uses the `Animal` as the constructor function and `Animal.prototype` as the newly created object's prototype, ignoring `Animal.prototype.constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

All JavaScript objects inherit properties and methods from a prototype. Once it gets inherited, you can directly call or change the value of it.

```
function Animal() {
  this.legs = 4;
}

var mouse = new Animal();

// mouse.__proto__.legs = 2;
//instead do this
mouse.legs = 2;
console.log(mouse.legs);
```